# Microphone stopped working after installing pavucontrol Arch

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio

I have been using Arch for quite some time now and the microphone used to work perfectly. But yesterday, I installed pavucontrol and suddenly the mic stopped working, i.e. no audio is picked up even though the mic is recognised by PulseAudio. 
I have ALSA installed as well. 
Here are some relevant info:

```
arecord -l                  
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any help is appreciated :) 
Edit: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. PulseAudio was already installed a long time ago, the output and input worked perfectly. But yesterday, when I installed pavucontrol, the mic stopped recording audio (I found out from a call) but it is recognised as an input device. 
Here's a screenshot of input devices from pavucontrol:
[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: Please edit question and explain if you only installed `pavucontrol` or Pulseaudio as well, how you found out your microphone is not working, and what `pavucontrol` shows when you try to record from the microphone. (Guess: it picks the wrong source).

Comment: idk if that's relevant to my problem but I can't record using `arecord`, I always get the error: `ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:600:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave` even though there is no other application using the mic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer, based on the information in the question so far:

If you have Pulseaudio running, Pulseaudio starts using all the ALSA `hw` devices, and you cannot use `arecord` directly on an ALSA device anymore. If you not only installed `pavucontrol`, but all of Pulseaudio, that would explain why it suddenly stopped working.

So use `parecord` instead of `arecord`, or use `arecord` on the `pulse` ALSA compatibility device instead of `dsnoop` or whatever you have in your ALSA configuration (I recommend changing your ALSA configuration to make `pulse` the default device), and use `pavucontrol` to ensure `arecord` points at the right source.

Comment: thank you very much! `parecord` worked perfectly. I also found out that `pulseaudio-alsa` package was not installed, so I installed it and the mic works perfectly. thanks again :)